# Better way to handle asynchronous log writing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-io

```
public static class LogWriter
{
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim writeLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public static void WriteExceptionLog(string content)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        MessageBox.Show(content);
        #endif
        WriteLog(content, Constant.EXCEPTION_LOG_PATH);
    }
    public static void WriteLog(string content, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            writeLock.EnterWriteLock();
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(directory)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                content = DateTime.Now + " : " + content;
                writeFile.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            writeLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class that writes logs. Because I am writing to a log asynchronously, I need to put a lock and release it when write is done but this seems to be somewhat of a clunky solution and maybe even bad for performance.

What is a better way to handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an existing logging library such as `NLog` or `log4Net`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reason and also to avoid a very different behavior between log-ON and log-OFF, I suggest to run one buffered log file per thread.

- One per thread to avoid locking: no contention
- Buffered to avoid disk latency

The counterparts are:

- a merging tools based on time (milliseconds) is needed to see application activity as a whole (vs thread activity)
- buffering may hide last log records in case of brutal termination

To go one step more to real-time, you have to log in memory, and to develop a dedicated interface to extract log on request  but this kind of log is generally reserved to hard real-time embedded application.

Other solution for safe logging with low CPU consumption (low level C programming):

- place a log record buffer into shared memory
- the observed process act as log record producer
- create a log manager process, with higher priority, which acts as log record consumer
- manage the communication between consumer and producer behind a flip/flop mechanism: a pointer assignment under critical section.

If the observed process crash, no log record will be lost since shared memory segment is attached to log manager process.

Comment: Thanks. I initially ruled buffer out of the question because I was afraid of not catching every errors but as this is getting computationally intensive, I will consider this option again.

Answer (score 0):

Opening, writing to, and then closing the file on each log request is both redundant and inefficient.

On your log class, use a buffer, and write that buffer's contents to the file, either every X requests, shutdown, or every Y minutes.